# How can launchers be added to and removed from the Unity dash?

Tags: 11.10, unity-dash, menu, games

**Scenario #1: Manually removing launchers**

I installed a few games from the recent Humble Indie Bundle and removed them today.

The games which were installed using a deb were successfully uninstalled and removed from the dash, however, the games that I installed using the .run format are still in my menu and dash even after uninstalling them... how do I remove those items?

**Scenario #2: Adding custom launchers**

I have created Wine shortcuts to card games on my Windows partition.  I added these launchers in `alacarte` (Menu Editor) and they worked fine in Classic Gnome, however they are not appearing in the Games section of the Unity dash. Is it possible to add launchers for these games to the dash, or do I have to add the launchers to the desktop?

Comment: I had a very similar question, and I was also unable to edit the Dash using the Menu Editor, so I expanded your question and added a bounty. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: @MichaelMS senario 2 wasnt as i had in mine... i use mediamonkey for organising and tagging my mp3, and it had created file association for all audio files and when i right click on the audio file and select open with i get 3-5 entries of mediamonkkey :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't know about scenario 1, haven't any HIB games, - I'd look thru any of the  possible places - /usr/local/share;` ~/.local/share; /opt/

As far as 2 - try opening the .desktop you created in a text editor (your launcher is just a .desktop), & add   a Categories= line

Something like this should suffice -

```
Categories=Game;
```

Typically game .desktops use this but the above should be ok

```
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Game;
```

A log out/in  should show in Dash filter > games, if not then re-open the launcher in your text editor & try adding a %U to end of the Exec= line leaving a space after what's currently there. (shouldn't be needed in these cases

Comment: it wasn in the ~/.local/share/applications directory,
i gave another look and the .desktop files werent conventionally named like "hammerfight.desktop"
their name started with thier developers and so did for mediamonkey, it all was wine-extensions-*EXT*

Comment: Thanks, that helped me solve #2. I'll update your answer once I've figured it out a bit more.

Answer (score 5):

Dash launchers are located in either /usr/share/applications/ or $HOME/.local/share/applications and have a .desktop extensions. To remove from the dash just delete the corresponding .desktop file from either of these folders. To add a launcher just create a new text document, save it with a suitable name (NAME.desktop) in one of those folders and here is a sample of what needs to go in it from the Chess game launcher file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Chess
Comment=Play the classic two-player boardgame of chess
Version=1.0
Exec=/usr/games/glchess
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=GNOME;Game;BoardGame;
StartupNotify=true
Icon=gnome-glchess
MimeType=application/x-chess-pgn;
G    enericName=3D Chess Game
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Bugzilla=GNOME
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Product=gnome-games
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Component=BugBuddyBugs
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Version=3.2.1
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=gnome-games
```

Answer (score 0):

In the dash type in Main Menu and run that application. Find the launchers created. Since these are from HIB they are probably are under the Games section. You can either uncheck the check box to hide the launcher entries or delete them.
If you are unable to find the launchers there they may be inside your ~/.local/share/applications/ folder.

Comment: nopes and nothing happening with main menu