# PPA for Android Studio?

Tags: ppa, android

[Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html) was released a few days ago and it's still in *early access preview*, but I would like to know if there is any PPA I could add to my Ubuntu Raring to automatically keep it updated with `apt-get`?

Comment: I don't know if it should have one. IntelliJ Idea likes to be installed per user as it updates itself.

Comment: @Grzegorz: Android Studio [is not IntelliJ Idea](http://blog.jetbrains.com/blog/2013/05/15/intellij-idea-is-the-base-for-android-studio-the-new-ide-for-android-developers/), but even IntelliJ Idea has a package: `intellij-idea-ce`.

Comment: I am using both. Android Studio is based on IntelliJ Idea 13 (it's in the article you cited!) and the same update mechanism is used for both, it just uses different [update site] (http://dl.google.com/android/studio/patches/updates.xml).

Comment: IntelliJ Idea has an entry in Ubuntu Software Center but it does not have Debian package in repository. See http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/allpackages

Comment: @Grzegorz: I see. Still, by installing the `intellij-idea-ce` package I have access to it directly from my dash. I don't know if it's just me but with Android Studio I always have to do `~/android-studio/bin/studio.sh`, locking it to the launcher doesn't work. As a side question, are you using OpenJDK or Sun Java?

Comment: @Grzegorz: To be honest I don't know exactly what the difference is, as long as I can install it via apt-get (as I did) or USC and it integrates nicely, all is good.

Comment: We are getting offtopic. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/93678/how-can-launchers-be-added-to-and-removed-from-the-unity-dash for dash shortcut.

Comment: For an updated question and answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1143634/is-there-a-repository-for-android-studio

Answer (score 10):

Since no official release yet, I made it for myself (which is 13.10 `saucy` -- I didn't know will it be compatible with other version of Ubuntu?)

```
add-apt-repository ppa:neizod/ppa
apt-get update
apt-get install android-studio-installer
```

This package does not resolve Java dependency, you still need to install it manually. My recommend is to use `oracle-java7-installer` package from `ppa:webupd8team/java`.

On installation, it will download zip file which size is approx 400MB, so make sure you have at lease 1GB (2 x 400MB) available. Zip file will be auto-remove after installed.

The program directory will be `/usr/lib/android-studio/`, only one command export to `/usr/bin/` is `android-studio`, which is symlink to `/usr/lib/android-studio/bin/studio.sh`. If you need other commands, call it with full path under root role, e.g.

```
sudo /usr/lib/android-studio/sdk/platform-tools/fastboot
```

I also put `android-studio.desktop` into `/usr/share/applications/`, so another way to start program is to use Unity lens and search for `Android Studio` (might need a reboot to make it show).

Answer (score 8):

There is no need of external PPA anymore since Canonical released `Ubuntu make` that allow an easiest installation of `Android Studio`:

#### Installing Ubuntu Make :

**For Ubuntu 14.04, 14.10 users :**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-desktop/ubuntu-make
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-make
```

**For Ubuntu 15.04 and up :**

Ubuntu make is already in official repositories, run :

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-make
```

---

#### Installing Android Studio :

```
umake android android-ndk
```

#### Uninstall Android Studio :

```
umake android --remove
```

Comment: Bless you :-) I don't understand why no upvotes against this post.

Comment: @ashubuntu It is less upvoted as this answer fails to explain that `how this is going to help`. Please consider editing if you can explain this.

Answer (score 3):

Android Studio, has no ppa available at the moment of writing (10-17-2013), so you are stuck building and installing the Linux package as presented in the [installation guide](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html). Of course, if you have the knowledge to create Debian packages, feel free to do so.

Comment: It's [listed](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html#download-ide-button) as an **early-access preview** so once it's considered stable (in Google terms) it'd be a likely candidate for inclusion in the default repositories alongside the `android-tools-*` packages.

Comment: @Alastair That's why I said **"at the moment of writing"** with the caveat that I will update once the conditions changes.

Comment: Sorry, @braiam - I wasn't directing that at you, I voted for your answer. I was just adding some extra info. as to the reason why. :)

Answer (score 3):

I'm packaging these tools for Gajj Distro, if lauchpad will allocate more space to my repo android studio will be available by the evening.

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linuxgndu/gajj-sci
```

For 14.04 use

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linuxgndu/adt-raring


 sudo apt-get update
```

For Android Developers Tool

```
  sudo apt-get install adt
```

For Android Studio

```
  sudo apt-get install android-studio
```

You also have to install Android-sdk

```
  sudo apt-get install android-sdk
  sudo sh /opt/android-sdk/install-sdk
```

You can also help me testing my package builds, bcz i'm newbie i don't know that much about ppa & packaging.

Answer (score 3):

The canonical way to install seems to be ubuntu-make https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-make

Answer (score 2):

I've just packaged **Android Studio for Ubuntu.**

You can install it from here: http://paolorotolo.github.io/android-studio/

Answer (score 1):

An automatically kept up to date PPA and with many fixes: https://mfonville.github.io/android-studio/

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:maarten-fonville/android-studio
sudo apt update
```

Then, you can either install:

- [Stable](https://developer.android.com/studio/) version.

  ```
  sudo apt install android-studio
  ```
- [Preview](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/) version.

  ```
  sudo apt install android-studio-preview
  ```

Answer (score 0):

There is an unofficial PPA from Paolo Ratolo (Italian teenager from Numix team). Here is how you can do it:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:paolorotolo/android-studio
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install android-studio
```

Source: http://itsfoss.com/install-android-studio-ubuntu-linux/