# Is there a repository for Android Studio?

Tags: apt, android, repository, android-studio, android-sdk

The download page for [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio) does not list any repositories, it only offers direct download links. I noticed that there are many Android SDK and tools packages in the Ubuntu repos, but no Android Studio. Is there a frequently updated repository or PPA available for Android Studio?

This question was asked [a long time ago](https://askubuntu.com/questions/297141/ppa-for-android-studio) back when Android Studio was still in a preview state, however, the answers are all very different and many of the answers consist of custom PPAs, many of which probably do not exist anymore for modern versions of Ubuntu. Therefore, this question needs to be re-asked so that we can collect updated instructions.

Comment: On the other hand, you could provide an answer to the question to which you linked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're looking for up to date PPA for Android Studio, it is [`ppa:maarten-fonville/android-studio`](https://launchpad.net/~maarten-fonville/+archive/ubuntu/android-studio)— at the time of writing this PPA has supported Ubuntu version up to `19.04` which is current latest release.

Add the PPA.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:maarten-fonville/android-studio
sudo apt-get update
```

Then, you can either install:

- [Stable](https://developer.android.com/studio/) version.

  ```
  sudo apt-get install android-studio
  ```
- [Preview](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/) version.

  ```
  sudo apt-get install android-studio-preview
  ```

Comment: This automatically downloads the `android-studio-ide-…-linux.tar.gz` file offered on the download page for Android Studio and installs it together with dependencies. Helps to keep it up to date automatically, but it's of course not the best way to build a `.deb`. It could be much smaller than 760 MiB by depending on other packages.

Answer (score -1):

no need for adding an external repository, `android-sdk` includes Android Studio!

Comment: Just installed android-sdk on Xubuntu 18.04, and there was no Android Studio.

Comment: the package only provide the installer for Android Studio.

Comment: @eadmaster May you elaborate on how to install Android Studio, once having installed `android-sdk` APT package?